# julia remote worker using "machinefile"-- ERROR: connect: host is unreachable (EHOSTUNREACH)

Tags: julia

I'm trying to set up a remote worker pool for parallel processing in julia; the "driver" machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 with the following configuration:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.1
Commit c03f413 (2014-09-21 21:30 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_LAPACK NO_LAPACKE DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: liblapack.so.3
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

And the remote machine is running CentOS 7.0:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.1
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_LAPACKE DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblasp.so.0
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

I've got the SSH keys set up for passwordless login (which works fine from the command-line), but when I try to start julia with the CentOS machine as a remote worker I get this:

```
corey@flash:~/rti_julia$ julia --machinefile machinefile 
ERROR: connect: host is unreachable (EHOSTUNREACH)
 in wait at ./task.jl:284
 in wait at ./task.jl:194
 in stream_wait at stream.jl:263
 in wait_connected at stream.jl:301
 in Worker at multi.jl:113
 in create_worker at multi.jl:1064
 in start_cluster_workers at multi.jl:1028
 in addprocs_internal at multi.jl:1234
 in addprocs at multi.jl:1244
 in process_options at ./client.jl:240
 in _start at ./client.jl:354
 in _start_3B_1714 at /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/sys.so

corey@flash:~/rti_julia$ Master process (id 1) could not connect within 60.0 seconds.
exiting.
```

I've checked /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure on the CentOS machine, and it does show that an SSH client connected successfully.

I suspect what is happening is that the worker process starts on the remote machine (CentOS), but the master process on the Ubuntu machine for some reason is unable to connect to the worker process that is spawned on the CentOS machine.  (Hence the status message I get at the end: "Master process (id 1) could not connect within 60.0 seconds.   exiting.")

The odd part about this is that if I use the CentOS machine as the "master" and the Ubuntu machine as the remote worker, everything works fine.

What can I do to make it work coming from the Ubuntu machine?  Thank you.